# how to fix printing issue when splitting data from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, text-files

I am having an issue where when I get the program to print the arrays with the split data in it the arrays are not words. They turn out looking like this:

[[Ljava.lang.String;@4aa298b7, [Ljava.lang.String;@7d4991ad, [Ljava.lang.String;@28d93b30,...
[[Ljava.lang.String;@66d3c617, [Ljava.lang.String;@63947c6b, [Ljava.lang.String;@2b193f2d,...

This error seems to be specific to my code. I am using a text file not a manually entered array.

I am not sure what is happening to cause them to print out in this manner. 
Any advice or corrections are greatly appreciated.

Here is my code currently:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SATVocabPractice {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ArrayList words = new ArrayList(); //Word arrays 
        ArrayList definitions = new ArrayList(); //Definition arrays. 

        //Build reader instance
        //Read data.csv
        //Default seperator is comma
        //Default quote character is double quote
        //Start reading from line number 2 (line numbers start from zero)
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SAT Vocab Practice/src/sat/vocab/practice/Words.txt"), '|', '"', 0);

        //Read CSV line by line and use the string array as you want
        String[] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            if (nextLine != null) {
                //Verifying the read data here
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
                definitions.add(Arrays.toString(nextLine).split("|"));
                words.add(Arrays.toString(nextLine).split("\\|"));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(words); //Print the word list
        System.out.println(definitions); //Print the definitions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words)); //Print the word list
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(definitions)); //Print the definitions
```

Comment: This did not work there was an error message saying:
no suitable method found for toString(ArrayList)
Then stating that none of the types were applicable (i.e. Arrays.toString(long[]), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

The method `Arrays.toString(nextLine)` doesn't work how you expect it to.

Try to loop through nextLine and add each content of the array to definitions seperately

Comment: `Ljava.lang.String;@` is returned where you used string arrays as strings. That's why he's getting the error